# Laravel Wordpress JSON REST API gives strange Curl error

Tags: php, json, wordpress, laravel, curl

I'm trying to use [laravel-wp-api](https://github.com/threesquared/laravel-wp-api) to get the posts from [a blog](http://idareyou.ee/blog/).  When I use `Postman` with `http://idareyou.ee/blog//wp-json/wp/v2/posts` I get a `200 OK HTTP response` and `Postman` shows the `JSON` result.

The following `Laravel` `BlogController` `getPosts()` method prints in the browser this `Curl` error:

`{"error":{"message":"cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host '\u003Cwp_location\u003E' (see http:\/\/curl.haxx.se\/libcurl\/c\/libcurl-errors.html)"},"results":[],"total":0,"pages":0}`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use WpApi;
class BlogController extends Controller
{
  public function getPosts()
  {

    $posts = WpApi::posts('http://idareyou.ee/blog//wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
    echo json_encode($posts,true); 

    //return view('pages.blog', ['active'=>'navBlog'])->with('posts', $posts  );
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my app I am fetching successfully some pictures from Instagram API using the following.  Do I need a similar 'fetchData' function in my `BlogController`?

```
function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/.......");
$result = json_decode($result, true);
$lastFive = array_slice($result['data'], 0, 5);   // returns last 5 instagram pics
```

Can anybody give me any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the config file for this service - my guess is you need to set-up the endpoint (blog domain) for your calls. So once you run `php artisan vendor:publish` you should have a specific config file under app/config - see if there's a setting there you need to change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I think you were right.  I set the endpoint to `'endpoint' => ' http://idareyou.ee/blog//wp-json/',` and now I get a `404 error` `{"error":{"message":"Client error: 404","code":404},"results":[],"total":0,"pages":0}`

Comment: Right - did you adjust your API call too, though? I suspect you now just pass in your relative path: `$posts = WpApi::posts('wp/v2/posts');` (also, just to be safe, I'd remove the double slashes in your endpoint, before "wp-json": "http://idareyou.ee/blog/wp-json/")

Comment: Thanks.  I now have the endpoint as `'endpoint' => 'http://idareyou.ee/blog/wp-json/',` and the call as you suggested `$posts = WpApi::posts('wp/v2/posts');` but I still get `{"error":{"message":"Client error: 404","code":404},"results":[],"total":0,"pages":0}`

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with the laravel-wp-api service, so discovering along with you... I think you don't even need a url there. So try this instead: `'endpoint' => 'http://idareyou.ee/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/',` and then `$posts = WpApi::posts();` -- the only parameter to the ApApi::posts call is a page number. (as in to get page 2, `$posts = WpApi::posts(2);`)

Comment: Brilliant!  You're a life saver.  That works.  Cheers